# ng-view fail to render

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
//app.js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/',
        {
            controller: 'customersController',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/customers.html'
        }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
}());
```

I have `/app/app.js` and `/app/views/customers.html` also `/app/customersController.js`.

Below is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head> 
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>

    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Assets/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/customersController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the controller:

```
(function () {

    var customersController = function customersController($scope) {
        $scope.sortBy = 'name';
        $scope.reverse = false;


        $scope.customers = [{ name: 'foo', city: 'ny' }, { name: 'bar', city: 'la' }];

        $scope.doSort = function (propname) {
            $scope.sortBy = propname;
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };
    };

    customersController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    angular.module('app', []).controller('customersController', customersController);

}());
```

customers.html is as follows:

```
test


<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers ">
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

It doesnt load customers.html, let alone `test` text on top.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are redefining your module.
Try changing this line

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('customersController', customersController);
```

to this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('customersController', customersController);
```